# Read gRPC metadata in Python server

Tags: python, grpc

I have client like this:

```
def run():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
    metadata = [('key', "value")]
    response = stub.SayHello(
        helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'),
        metadata=metadata
    )
    print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
```

And server:

```
class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):    
    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)
```

So, in server, how can I read metadata sent by client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ServicerContext.invocation_metadata

We can use `context.invocation_metadata()` to access client's metadata

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit on top of the right answer for --

You can retrieve the data like a dictionary e.g

```
metadict = dict(context.invocation_metadata())
userid = metadict['userid']
```

Also, I would highly recommend checking out gprc example repo for more advanced use cases [-here-](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/auth/customized_auth_server.py#L46) using ServerInterceptor